# Pydev requires latest version of Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I have downloaded Eclipse Oxygen and installed it yesterday. When I try to install PyDev, I get an error:

> This version of PyDev requires a newer version of Eclipse to run.

The latest version is not even out yet until next year. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: PyDev requires Java 8 and Eclipse 4.6 (Neon) in order to run and only supports Python 2.6 onwards

Comment: Just found Neon here: https://www.genuitec.com/eclipse-neon/

Comment: On the Eclipse website the latest version is Oxygen. I downloaded Neon from a third-party website.

Comment: PyDev should work with Eclipse Oxygen. From where do you installed PyDev? Maybe you have an older version of PyDev... http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/pydev-python-ide-eclipse

Comment: It will support eclipse versions above 4.6 I have PyDev on Oxygen Elcipse installed and it works fine.

Comment: Would be so kind as to write it as an answer (not comment) so I can mark it  as the right answer?